# How can I extract decisions from a tree object of the R package rpart?

Tags: r, extract, rpart, coefficients

I use the package `rpart`to model a classification/regression tree.
I have the variables x,y,s where x is in {-1,1}, y is continuous in [0,1] and s$is a factor with 3 levels.

I use

```
fit <- rpart(x~y+s, data=data, method="class")
```

The final model makes perfect sense, I can plot it using `fancyRpartPlot(fit)`.
I can also prune the tree and only one decision is left:

```
fit = prune(fit,cp=0.1)
```

It says that $y$ needs to be smaller than some threshold. How can I extract this threshold? I would like to do bootstrap runs on the data set and keep the threshold in an array.

Answer (score 0):

The field `split` in the `rpart` object holds the decision boundaries.
The solution is

```
threshold =  fit$split[1,foo]
```